# How to delete selected listbox value in userform using data imported from separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

When I have the user click on a button to open a userform it displays a listbox (empList) containing a list of employees.

The data is retrieved through a hidden sheet within the workbook called "Employees" when the userform is initialized.

I have an "Add" button and "Delete" button to add or delete employees from the list. The add button seems to work by adding a value to the end of the list by inserting the new employee value into the next available open slot of column "A" in my Employees worksheet and refreshing the list to display the new changes.

By my knowledge I know how to remove a selected value from a listbox by targeting the list itself, but how can you delete a selected value on the list by removing it from the second sheet where the data is being imported?

Here is my code for the add button:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    'Declaring variable to store new name
    Dim Employee As String
    'Variable to store the length of rows in column.
    Dim lRow As Long
    'Gather User input of name
    Employee = Application.InputBox("Please Enter an Employee Name (No Numbers)", "Employee Name")
    'Add Employee to Employees sheet and refresh list
    Sheets("Employees").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Employee
    lRow = Sheets("Employees").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Employees").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    empList.RowSource = "Employees!A1:A" & lRow
End Sub
```

And here is my code for when the userform is initialized:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow =Sheets("Employees").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Employees").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    empList.RowSource = "Employees!A1:A" & lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to remove selected value from sheet `Employees` column `A `, and than reload listbox in your your userform, am I right?

Comment: That's right. I want the user to select a value inside the listbox within the userform and have it be deleted from the second sheet "Employees". Then have the listbox be updated to show the value has been removed so when I close the userform and come back the value will no longer be there. Like I did with the add button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not set on using "RowSource." Here is a different approach.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnClear_Click()

'Declaring variable to store new name
Dim Employee As String
Dim wsEmployee As Excel.Worksheet
'Variable to store the length of rows in column.
Dim lRow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim oCell As Range

empList.RowSource = ""

Set wsEmployee = Sheets("Employees")

LastRow = wsEmployee.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each oCell In wsEmployee.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    If oCell.Value = empList.Value Then
        oCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next oCell

lRow = wsEmployee.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

empList.Clear

For Each oCell In wsEmployee.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    If oCell.Value <> "" Then
        empList.AddItem oCell.Value
    End If
Next oCell

CleanUp:

Set wsEmployee = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim oCell As Range
Dim wsEmployee As Excel.Worksheet

Set wsEmployee = Sheets("Employees")

empList.RowSource = ""

lRow = wsEmployee.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each oCell In wsEmployee.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    If oCell.Value <> "" Then
        empList.AddItem oCell.Value
    End If
Next oCell

CleanUp:

Set wsEmployee = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
'Declaring variable to store new name
Dim Employee As String
Dim oCell As Range
Dim wsEmployee As Excel.Worksheet
'Variable to store the length of rows in column.
Dim lRow As Long, LastRow As Long

Set wsEmployee = Sheets("Employees")

LastRow = wsEmployee.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'Gather User input of name
Employee = Application.InputBox("Please Enter an Employee Name (No Numbers)", "Employee Name")
    'Add Employee to Employees sheet and refresh list
wsEmployee.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = Employee

lRow = wsEmployee.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

empList.Clear

    For Each oCell In wsEmployee.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
        If oCell.Value <> "" Then
            empList.AddItem oCell.Value
        End If
    Next oCell

CleanUp:

Set wsEmployee = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click()

'Declaring variable to store new name
Dim Employee As String
Dim wsEmployee As Excel.Worksheet
'Variable to store the length of rows in column.
Dim lRow As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim oCell As Range

empList.RowSource = ""

Set wsEmployee = Sheets("Employees")

LastRow = wsEmployee.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each oCell In wsEmployee.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
If oCell.Value = empList.Value Then
    Employee = Application.InputBox("Please Edit an Employee Name (No Numbers)", "Employee Name")
    oCell.Value = Employee
End If
Next oCell

lRow = wsEmployee.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

empList.Clear

For Each oCell In wsEmployee.Range("A1:A" & lRow)
If oCell.Value <> "" Then
    empList.AddItem oCell.Value
End If
Next oCell

CleanUp:

Set wsEmployee = Nothing

End Sub
```

I hope that helps you out.  I am at work at the moment.  If you would like further assistance please let me know and i will add in better notes. I build it and tested it. It will delete the entire row. let me know if you would like just the name deleted.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for and its way better utilized with the for each loop. Thank you! :D If you have a way to delete a certain value within a column like column "A" that would be helpful to know in case I decide to use more columns for information. But regardless, this solved my problem!

Comment: I added a new button to the end to edit a name not delete it. Let me know if you need any other help. Have a great day!